# Changing image upload size limit in Django-summernote

Tags: django, summernote

I'm using [django-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote).  How can I change the file size upload limit? I get the error: "Got an error uploading an image: File size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be used" when I try to add an image using the summernote widget's toolbar.

I can found it in the source [here](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/blob/b26fe19992d25634bbe4c3f6c27ba2a2182e51ea/django_summernote/templates/django_summernote/widget_iframe_editor.html), but it's as far as I could get:

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the image upload limit settings using [`SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG`](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote#options) settings.

You need to add `attachment_filesize_limit` setting with your desired value to your summernote settings.

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    ...
    'attachment_filesize_limit': custom_file_limit, # specify the file size
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Where did you find that setting? It's not in those docs.

Comment: Yes, even i could not find that in the docs. I then looked into the official summernote [settings.py](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/blob/288595fcc53f7ad619b584e365b003031bbc88d3/django_summernote/settings.py) file and found this setting which could be configured. Hope it helps!