# How to Change File Upload Size Limit Django Summernote

Tags: django, summernote

I'm using Django-summernote. I have installed it by pip install django-summernote command. How can I change the file size upload limit? I get the error: "File size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be saved" when I try to add an image using the summernote widget's toolbar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing image upload size limit in Django-summernote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615292/changing-image-upload-size-limit-in-django-summernote)

Comment: in settings.py i have use 'SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    ...
    'attachment_filesize_limit': custom_file_limit, # specify the file size
}'
But this is not working

@lucutzu33

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by the following steps:

In--> settings.py, globally declare max_image_pixel:

```
MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = int(1024 * 1024 * 1024 // 4 // 3)
```

Then in the same --> settings.py, do the following:

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
  ...
 'attachment_filesize_limit': MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS,
  }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615292/changing-image-upload-size-limit-in-django-summernote)